# I have altered table with adding new columns.Now i want to add records into specific row

Tags: sql

In my employee table I have altered table with adding new columns department salary and lastname. Now I want to add records into specific row.

```
EMPLOYEE( ID NUMBER -  4 0 -  nullable -  -  
  NAME VARCHAR2 10 -  -  -  nullable -  -  
  AGE NUMBER -  4 0 -  nullable -  -  
  LOCATION VARCHAR2 10 -  -  -  nullable -  -  
  DEPT VARCHAR2 10 -  -  -  nullable -  -  
  LASTNAME VARCHAR2 10 -  -  -  nullable -  -  
  SALARY NUMBER -  9 0 -  nullable -  -  
  DEPARTMENT VARCHAR2 10 -  -  -  nullable -  -  
  JOINING DATE 7 -  -  -  nullable -  -  )
```

1 - 9

Comment: Did you hear about UPDATE? That SQL command might prove useful...

Comment: I know update, but it will not work for inserting record for newly added column in a table.

Comment: Yes. `UPDATE` will work for adding values to newly added columns. They are probably stored as `NULL`. What values are you trying to add to and to what rows? We need more information.

Comment: Define "inserting record for newly added column". What is "record"? Which "column"? When are they "newly added"? Are you trying to do this manually or automatically? Show us a timeline: what is in the table before, what gets inserted, and what you then want to update. The question as asked is completely unclear.

Comment: suppose I have added new column 'Lastname' into a table.I want to add record in lastname in first row.

Comment: Right, so do an extremely basic `update` statement: `update employee set lastname = 'Smith' where id = 1;` or whatever, for each row. Or `update employee set lastname = case id when 1 then 'Smith' when 2 then 'Brown' ... else lastname end;` Or if that's too tedious, consider a `merge` from a file, however your DBMS enables that. Speaking of which, what is your DBMS? MySQL/MariaDB? SQL Server? PostgreSQL? something else? You should tag it whenever you can, which is nearly always, because few people ask 'pure SQL' questions; it's always specific to some dialect.

Comment: @underscore_d thank u...

Comment: @bighneshsabat OK, and I've added some more ideas to my comment also. If you have more specific requirements, help us to help you by editing your post!

Comment: update employee set lastname=smith where firstname='john'; why this stuff not working?

Comment: Put quotes around string values: `'smith'`. Like I did. And please read a basic primer on SQL if you still don't know these things. SO expects people asking questions to have done slightly more background research than this.

Comment: I tried using 'smith' but 0 rows updated.

Comment: update employee set lastname='smith' where id=1; works fine .....                     update employee set lastname='smith' where firstname='john'; not working

Comment: @underscore_d sorry my mistakes it works...in both the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
   INSERT INTO your_table (column1, column2, column3)  
    VALUES ('value1', 'value2', 'value3');
```

Comment: my question is suppose column1,column2 have records and I add new column3 to the table then how I will add records to specific column?

Comment: You have to do an UPDATE query where COLUMN1 = VALUE1 (you can see an example of an update at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp).

Comment: Or you can simply use the INSERT query I posted above, and it should work (though it will add a new row to your table).